# Match and remember value of HTTP header in JMeter

Tags: java, http-headers, jmeter

There is HTTP Header Manager component, which allows to set some HTTP headers when HTTP Sampler is used.

I need to intercept response header with certain name, remember it in some variable and use the saved value in all requests (override existing values, for example I recorded 100500 requests with HTTP Proxy and don't want to alter all requests with providing the variable expression).

So the flow is something like below:

- send N requests to server
- in some response there is the header X
- send M requests
- send request with saved value of header X
- in some response value of header X changes, and subsequent requests with header X will use the new saved value

Shall I create some controller for such behavior or there is something ready-to-use? didn't spot it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) is your friend. You can tell it to parse the headers as well as the body.

Comment: Is it possible to define single extractor for set of HTTP Samplers? As far as I understood, it has to be defined after each Sampler?

Comment: It is possible but the result stored in the output variable will only ever reflect the most recent sample. It will not perform a single search over multiple results but instead, run a separate search after each sample.